# Similarties of ASP.NET and Java web application

Tags: c#, java, architecture, web-applications

I would like to know what are the equivilents of these features of C# asp.net 
compared to a similar java built web application.

Would a java based web application still be created in this fashion:

```
web.site
    html files, javascripts, css
web.business
    business logic, rules, etc.
web.entities
    person, account, cart....
web.dataAccess
    basic CRUD access
```

I'm pretty sure that in the business and entity sections that C# and Java
would be very similar to each other with complied libraries of the correct
file types. In the dataAccess section, there is alot of similarities such
as hibernate/nHibernate, ORMS and such, so I'm not too worried about that.
But the site section is a little fuzzy. ASP.NET would have the
.aspx file with a .aspx.cs codebehind, but I have no idea what a java site 
would have. Are these js files, jar files, servlets, applets...haven't a clue.

Can anyone go into any detail about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go take a look at http://www.roseindia.net/ I've found it's pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

Basically its's equivalent of J2EE in .Net framework which includes (Asp.Net)

web.site (java)    html files, javascripts, css

web.site (.Net)    html files, javascripts, jQuery, css

---

web.business(java)    business logic, rules, etc.

web.business(.Net)    Same as java, with some differences like inheritance rules like multiple class inheritance in one go is not allowed in C#, as in java

---

web.entities(java)    person, account, cart....

web.entities(.Net)    person, account, cart....(Same as java)

---

web.dataAccess(jave)    basic CRUD access

web.dataAccess(.Net)    several options like
LINQ,
ODBC,
ADO.NET

---

See these links for design patterns (java apps)

http://www.indicthreads.com/2125/design-patterns-for-web-applications/

[www.javaworld.com](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2006/jw-0130-pojo.html)

you may like read this thread which is similar to probably what you are looking for

[java web applicaton layout, please explain some design principles/patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970836/java-web-applicaton-layout-please-explain-some-design-principles-patterns)

Comment: Can you go into any more detail about the layers that you're describing for the Java side of this?